# "...in a hospital that it should do the sick no harm." Is this structure normal?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Florence Nightingale noted,

> It may seem a strange principle to enunciate *as the very first requirement in a hospital that it should do the sick no harm*.

At the beginning of the 20th century, Dr Harvey Cushing, a pioneer in surgery and neurosurgery, published detailed descriptions of harm caused to his patients secondary to his own performance.

[Source](http://www.deepdyve.com/lp/elsevier/...nce-t06Mw2gGmh)

Could you please help me understand the structure of the italicized part?

Comment: What part of it don't you understand? Why do you think there might be a grammatical problem?

Comment: "It may seem a strange principle to enunciate that it should do the sick no harm".The second "It" refers to "the very first requirement in a hospital" that would be The doctors and nurses.

Comment: What is the antecedent of _it_ in that sentence? Nightingale was describing a requirement for hospitals.

Comment: "It may seem a strange principle to enunciate that the very first requirement in a hospital should do the sick no harm". Am I right?

Comment: @0935: no, in that sentence, the _requirement_ should do no harm. The original sentence means that _the hospital_ should do no harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the statement in several sources. Several (older) sources has it varying from yours:

> It may seem a strange principle to enunciate, as the very first requirement in a hospital, that it should do the sick no harm.

The sentence without the parenthetical, and substituting *a hospital* for *it* is

> It may seem a strange principle to enunciate that (a hospital) should do the sick no harm.

Ennunciate means to state or declare definitely, as a theory.

The sentence should now make perfect sense:

> It may seem a strange principle to declare that, as the very first requirement, (a hospital) should do the sick no harm.

Why wasn't it said that way? Because it was said, formally (which is always different that informal spoken speech, in 1859 (155 years ago). People spoke a bit differently then.

Comment: Thanks a million. Just one more Question: Is that Ok to rephrase that in this way:It may seem a strange principle to declare that a hospital, as the very first requirement, should do the sick no harm.

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't. To rephrase what you've written, I would say, *It may seem strange to need to declare that a hospital, as the very first requirement, should do the sick no harm.* Or: *It may seem a strange necessity to declare that a hospital, as the very first requirement, should do the sick no harm.* A requirement is a need or necessity.

Answer (score 1):

*the very first requirement* means *the most important requirement*.

*in a hospital* means that the requirement applies to hospitals.

*that it should do the sick no harm* means that hospitals shouldn't make sick people even sicker (or kill them). *it* refers to the hospitals mentioned in the previous phrase.

The quote could be rephrased as:

> It may seem a strange principle to enunciate that the most important requirement of a hospital is that it should not harm the patients.

Nightingale was apparently trying to make use of the phrase *first do no harm*, which is commonly assumed to come from the Hippocratic Oath. That precise phrase doesn't actually appear in the Oath, but *do no harm* is in the Hippocratic Corpus. See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primum_non_nocere

Answer (score 1):

> It may seem a strange principle to enunciate as the very first requirement in a hospital that it should do the sick no harm.

Let's simplify things a bit:

> Maybe it is strange (to define as the very first requirement in a hospital) that it should do the sick no harm.

Now let's remove the part in parentheses and replace it with *say*; that will actually not really change the meaning much! *it* further on refers to *hospital*, so we have to keep that in:

> Maybe it is strange to say that a hospital should do the sick no harm.

Seeing your (now deleted) comment, I think you may have been thinking that the *requirement* should do no harm, but it is the *hospital* that should do no harm.